# What is the set of units in $ (\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)$ equal to $\{k+n \mathbb Z : gcd(n,k)=1\} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-group

I have been learning about quotient rings, and have come across the following ring: $ (\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)$, the ring of residue classes mod $n$.

I have found that the set of units in $ (\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)$ is $$ (\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z) ^X = \{k+n \mathbb Z : gcd(n,k)=1\} $$

How can I see that this is true?

Answer (score 1):

One inclusion is straightforward. The other follows from the existence of the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).